# Is it possible to apply a grayscale image as view mask in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mask

Is it possible to use a views `.mask(...)` modifier together with a grayscale image. I mean just like one uses a layer mask in Photoshop.

While it is not problem to use an `Image` as mask view, this results in a simple rectangle mask with the size of the image. The image content is not considered for masking.

I would like use an image as mask to apply a complex opacity mask, e.g. like the cloud in [this image](https://www.istockphoto.com/de/foto/white-cloud-isoliert-auf-schwarzem-hintergrund-schwarzer-himmel-und-einzelne-wei%C3%9Fe-gm1077506500-288628404)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to convert the image to use alpha depending on luminance - a perfect use for the [`luminanceToAlpha()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link/luminancetoalpha()) modifier.

Result:

[image: Text on red background masked by cloud texture]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a red view with some text") // 1
            .padding(50)
            .background(Color.red)
            .mask { // 2
                Image("cloud") // 3
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 350)
                    .luminanceToAlpha() // 4
                    .fixedSize() // 5
            }
    }
}
```

How it works:

1. Text is made, surrounded by padding, with a red background
2. We mask the image after applying transformations
3. The image is first resized to fit a 350px width
4. The image is converted from grayscale to alpha
5. The image is a fixed size, meaning it can't be influenced by the space given by the mask